# How to get itemId of the item you are replying/forwarding to using Office-JS

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

Is there a way to get the itemId of the item you are replying/forwarding to in compose mode using the Office-JS library or EWS? I want to be able to get the itemid of the email or meeting invite that I am replying/forwarding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`OfficeJS` doesn't provide anything for that. Basically your add-in is run under the context of a specific item in Outlook (currently selected). The best what you could do is to use EWS by calling `Office.context.mailbox.makeEwsRequestAsync` or Graph API (for Office365 users). You may take a look at the [EWS - Determine if an e-mail is a reply or has been forwarded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32718758/ews-determine-if-an-e-mail-is-a-reply-or-has-been-forwarded) thread, you are interested in getting the `In-Reply-To` field. Note that `In-Reply-To` is an optional field so it may not always be populated.